# Active Record: Change the values of certain items in the database through terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Say I have this table created:

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :contents do |t|
      t.string :user_id
      t.string :content
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :contents
  end
end
```

How could I change, through terminal, the value of user_id for a specific content of which I have the ID and save it for testing purposes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the content with the id of 1 to have a user_id of 5 (assuming user_id is an integer field):

run `rails console`, then `Content.update(1, user_id: 5)`